# remote validation client side hook

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I am using remote validation with jquery and unobtrusive javascript in my MVC 3 project. Now when the remote validation fails I want to make more modifications to the page then just displaying the error message. How can I hook into the remote validation failure from javascript?

Answer (score 3):

MVC validation adds input-validation-error class to an element what failed validation. So I would bind to onChange event of input element and I would check if it validated fine or failed. below code should do the trick

```
$('#yourInputId').change(function(){
   if($(this).hasClass('input-validation-error')){
     // do your thing here
   }
});
```

If you need to check for a particular validation error you can go further. This is what gets added if my remove validation fails:

```
<span class="field-validation-error" data-valmsg-for="Account.Login" data-valmsg-replace="true">
   <span for="Account_Login" generated="true" class="">Login is taken. Maybe  Login1 will work for you? </span>
</span>
```

So you can check for a specific string being added to the DOM.

Comment: I like the idea unfortunatly the field can not validate for two reasons. a) the email address is not in a valid format. b) it's already registered. I only want to hook into the second thing to show a forgot password link in that case.